# Вывод из бд на php

Tags: php, база-данных, циклы, выборка

Требуется при нажатии на пункт меню *"одежда-мужская"*, что бы открывал каталог и делал выборку из мужской одежды (`category=1`), при нажатии на *"женскую-выборка"* из женской из бд и тд.

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";

     if(isset($_POST['men'])){
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product where category=1",$link);
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         do{
             echo '
                 <div class="product box">
                     <div class="img_product">
                         <img src="/img/'.$row["image"].'" alt="">
                     </div>
                     <h2>'.$row["name"].'</h2>
                     <p class="price">'.$row["price"].' руб.</p>
                     <p>'.$row["description"].'</p>
                 </div>
             ' ;
         }
         while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
     }
?>
```

Поместила это в каталог, но не выводит.
Может поможет кто решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить вот такой выход:

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '
             <div class="product box">
                 <div class="img_product">
                     <img src="/img/'.$row["image"].'" alt="">
                 </div>
                 <h2>'.$row["name"].'</h2>
                 <p class="price">'.$row["price"].' руб.</p>
                 <p>'.$row["description"].'</p>
             </div>
         ' ;
}
```

**P.S.** Советую использовать **PDO**, вместо **mysql** или **mysqli**, это немного упростит работу.